# value of stateid is not passing to controller

Tags: codeigniter

In the below script, the value of `stateId` is not passing to the controller. Can any one help me with this?

```
$("#ddlState").bind("change",function() {
    var stateId = $(this).val();
    $("#div_city_wrapper").load("page/new_city", {"stateId": stateId}, function(r) {
        alert('done loading'); 
    });
});
```

Comment: Show the controller? your example is super vague.

Comment: You really need to add more information here, or the question will likely be closed.

Answer (score 0):

Add the extra `alert` with the comment next to it to your JavaScript:

```
$("#ddlState").bind("change",function()
{
   var stateId = $(this).val();

   alert(stateId); // if this isn't null or undefined, then the problem is in your controller

   $("#div_city_wrapper").load("page/new_city", {"stateId": stateId}, function(r) {
       alert('done loading'); 
    });
});
```

If the problem is in your controller, then you need to add it as a parameter, e.g.

```
function new_city($stateId = NULL)
{
    if ($stateId === NULL)
    {
        // nothing was passed to the controller, so redirect somewhere or display an error
    }

    // the rest of your function...
}
```